# Running time Array#unshift vs Array#shift

Tags: ruby, arrays, performance

I expected the running time of `Array#shift` and `Array#unshift` both to be `Θ(n)`. Reason being that the machine needs to loop through each array member and assign it to the key left or right to it.

In the case of `Array#unshift`, assuming that only one value is passed in as an argument and that there are lots of array members, I assumed that the value assignment for `array[0]` is not having a significant impact on the running time. In other words, when the number of array members is high and the number of variables passed into `Array#unshift` is low, I expected `Array#shift` and `Array#unshift` to have the same running time.

When running benchmarks on Ruby 2.1.2, these assumptions do not hold true. Why?

Code:

```
require 'benchmark'

GC.disable    

number_of_elements = 25_600_000

a1 =[]
a2 = []
a3 = []
a4 = []
q1 = Queue.new
q2 = Queue.new

puts number_of_elements

number_of_elements.times do
  q1.enq(true)
  q2.enq(true)
  a1 << true
  a2 << true
  a3 << true
  a4 << true
end

number_of_operations = 1

Benchmark.bm do |bm|
  puts "Queue#enq('test')"
  bm.report do    
    number_of_operations.times { q1.enq('test') }
  end

  puts "Queue#deq"
  bm.report do    
    number_of_operations.times { q2.deq }
  end

  puts "Array#shift"
  bm.report do
    number_of_operations.times { a1.shift }
  end 

  puts "Array#unshift"
  bm.report do
    number_of_operations.times { a2.unshift('test') }    
  end 

  puts "Array#pop"
  bm.report do
    number_of_operations.times { a3.pop }
  end

  puts "Array#<<"
  bm.report do
    number_of_operations.times { a4 << 'test' }
  end      
end
```

Result:

```
25600000
       user     system      total        real
Queue#enq('test')
   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000006)
Queue#deq
   0.010000   0.020000   0.030000 (  0.029928)
Array#shift
   0.010000   0.020000   0.030000 (  0.032203)
Array#unshift
   0.080000   0.060000   0.140000 (  0.143272)
Array#pop
   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000004)
Array#<<
   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000007)
```

Comment: What happens if you crank up the number of operations?

Comment: #shift@12.8m: 0.016307, #shift@25.6m: 0.059878, #shift@64m: 0.098583, #shift@128m: 0.344900. #unshift@12.8m: 0.059736, #unshift@25.6m: 0.126382, #unshift@64m: 0.285351, #unshift@128m: 0.993967. By comparing only these ratios, it would seem that #shift runs at Θ(3.4n) and #unshift slightly exponential.

Comment: Have you studied the Ruby source code to understand how arrays are implemented and how `shift`/`unshift` work? There are all sorts of things that could be going on behind the scenes that will cloud your results. Adding an element to the beginning of an array does not necessarily allocate a single new entry for the array, it might allocate many or it might just move a array-starts-here pointer; similarly, `shift`ing an element might just update a pointer to point to the new index-0 address.

Comment: I had a look but it's written in C and with zero C experience I struggle to understand it.

Comment: your question is pretty useless without mentioning which ruby version you use

Comment: you should also disable garbage collection during your runs

Comment: Added Ruby version 2.1.2 to the question.

Comment: Disabled garbage collection and updated benchmark results in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MRI Ruby 2.1.2, [`unshift`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-unshift) does realloc the array and copy it entirely:

```
              static VALUE
rb_ary_unshift_m(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE ary)
{
    long len = RARRAY_LEN(ary);

    [...]

    ary_ensure_room_for_unshift(ary, argc);
    ary_memcpy(ary, 0, argc, argv);
    ARY_SET_LEN(ary, len + argc);
    return ary;
}
```

[`shift`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-unshift) apparently does not always do something like that:

```
              static VALUE
rb_ary_shift_m(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE ary)
{
    VALUE result;
    long n;

    [...]

    rb_ary_modify_check(ary);
    result = ary_take_first_or_last(argc, argv, ary, ARY_TAKE_FIRST);
    n = RARRAY_LEN(result);
    if (ARY_SHARED_P(ary)) {
        if (ARY_SHARED_OCCUPIED(ARY_SHARED(ary))) {
            ary_mem_clear(ary, 0, n);
        }
        ARY_INCREASE_PTR(ary, n);
    }
    else {
        RARRAY_PTR_USE(ary, ptr, {
            MEMMOVE(ptr, ptr + n, VALUE, RARRAY_LEN(ary)-n);
        }); /* WB: no new reference */
    }
    ARY_INCREASE_LEN(ary, -n);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: In some cases, the array has extra space at the front allocated for the purpose of unshift: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/fdbd3716781817c840544796d04a7d41b856d9f4

Comment: The above is as of 2.0, so this answer is a little misleading. It seems like for array sizes less than 64, this optimization doesn't happen, presumably because O(n) isn't so bad when n < 64